# Index a different range of indicies from each row of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I have two arrays of incidies with shape `m`. I need to take the mean of the values inbetween the indicies from an array with shape `m x n`. Can this be done without iterating through each row? What is the fastest way to do this?

```
idx0 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5])
idx1 = np.array([5, 8, 6, 7])
d = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]])
```

Desired result:

```
<< d[np.arange(d.shape[0]), idx0:idx1]
>> np.array([3.5, 6, 4.5, 6.5])
```

The best ways I've found to do this are list comprehension or using a for loop with numba, but this seems like it should be a common problem? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "mean of the values in between the indices". Can you explain how the desired results derive from the inputs?

Comment: For the first pair, (1, 5), I'm taking (2+3+4+5)/4 = 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you'd still need to get slices of pairwised ranges of indices from `idx0` and `idx1`.
`zip` + `slice` is a straigtforward way:

```
[d[:, slice(*a)].mean() for a in zip(idx0, idx1)]
```

---

```
[3.5, 6.0, 4.5, 6.5]
```

Comment: The OP said they know how to do it with a list comprehension. I think they're looking for a way to do it directly in numpy.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think he would find a "without iterating" way in numpy for that, that why I've written "*you'd still need*"

Comment: There is a way to keep it all in numpy. I posted it now

Answer (score 1):

If you work with `d.ravel()` instead of `d`, things will be easier, because now you can find the sums of elements using `np.add.reduceat` and compute averages directly from that.

The linear indices in `d.ravel()` corresponding to `idx0` and `idx1` are

```
idx0r = idx0 + d.shape[1] * np.arange(d.shape[0])
idx1r = idx1 + d.shape[1] * np.arange(d.shape[0])
```

To obtain a linear index of ranges to sum, you can do

```
idx = (np.stack((idx0, idx1), axis=-1) + d.shape[1] * np.arange(d.shape[0])[:, None]).ravel()
```

The reason that you want to have a 1D array for this is that you need to be able to remove the last element if it is equal to `d.size`, since `np.add.reduceat` does not accept indices past the end of the array:

```
if idx[-1] == d.size:
    idx = idx[:-1]
```

This last operation does not copy the data: it just creates a view that is one element short.

You can now sum directly:

```
sums = np.add.reduceat(d.ravel(), idx)[::2]
```

Taking every other element is required because the sums between the n-th element of `idx1` and n+1st element of `idx0` are also present in the sums.

Now you can normalize by the lengths of each segment:

```
means = sums / (idx1 - idx0)
```

**TL;DR**

```
idx = (np.stack((idx0, idx1), axis=-1) + d.shape[1] * np.arange(d.shape[0])[:, None]).ravel()
if idx[-1] == d.size:
    idx = idx[:-1]
means = np.add.reduceat(d.ravel(), idx)[::2] / (idx1 - idx0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it is masking instead of indexing. First you create the mask:

```
mask = np.zeros((d.shape[0], d.shape[1] + 1), np.int8)
mask[np.arange(d.shape[0]), idx0] = 1
mask[np.arange(d.shape[0]), idx1] = -1
mask = mask.cumsum(axis=1)[:, :-1].astype(bool)
```

The initial array is created with one extra column to accommodate the case where `idx1` contains elements that are at `d.size[1]`.

There are a number of approaches you can take going forward.

1. The first is probably simplest: using a masked array:

   ```
   means = np.ma.array(d, mask=~mask).mean(axis=1)
   ```
2. Another approach is to pre-multiply the data by the mask and compute your own sums:

   ```
   means = (d * mask).sum(axis=1) / (idx1 - idx0)
   ```
3. An third approach would be to apply the mask and use `np.add.reduceat` similarly to how the other answer suggests, but on the masked data, which avoids adding unnecessary numbers:

   ```
   n = (idx1 - idx0)
   means = np.add.reduceat(d[mask], np.r_[0, n[:-1].cumsum()]) / n
   ```